# MSCOMCTL.OCX Missing in Windows Server 2012

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2012-r2, ocx, windows-2003-webserver

I am trying to deploy all my executables from Windows Server 2003 to 2012 R2.
When i ran one of the exe's(VB6) it throws error:

```
ERROR: 339 - Component 'MSCOMCTL.OCX' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid
```

I know how to register MSCOMCTL.OCX in Windows Server.
But i went ahead and searched for this OCX in Windows Server 2003 where this exe has been running for over 5 years and to my surprise there was no MSCOMCTL.OCX there.

So how was the exe running fine on Windows Server 2003 without MSCOMCTL.OCX but on Windows Server 2012 it throws error?

Comment: Are you *sure* you searched everywhere? Anyway, why not just install the OCX? And it would be a good idea to document (and maybe automate) your deployment to avoid these headaches next time.

Comment: I searched everywhere, that's what surprises me how come i am not able to find this file in old server.

Comment: Anyways i registered this file and my app is working fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ship this file with your application. It's still supported in Server 2012 R2. You will find all information here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx

You find MSCOMCTL.OCX in the section: "Supported Runtime Files to Distribute with Your Application"